# Adding Alpha Channel to Volume in VTK

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

Hello everyone interested,

i am having a bit trouble to add an alpha channel to a volume (made from rgb tiffstack) in VTK.
In the Slicer3d App, i just add the following skript in the python shell to get this done:

```
colorVolume = slicer.mrmlScene.GetFirstNodeByClass("vtkMRMLVectorVolumeNode")

# Convert RGB image to RGBA
luminance = vtk.vtkImageLuminance()
luminance.SetInputConnection(colorVolume.GetImageDataConnection())
append=vtk.vtkImageAppendComponents()
append.AddInputConnection(colorVolume.GetImageDataConnection())
append.AddInputConnection(luminance.GetOutputPort())
append.Update()
colorVolume.SetAndObserveImageData(append.GetOutput())

# Enable volume rendering
volRenLogic = slicer.modules.volumerendering.logic()
displayNode = volRenLogic.CreateDefaultVolumeRenderingNodes(colorVolume)
displayNode.SetVisibility(True)
# Enable direct RGBA color mapping
displayNode.GetVolumePropertyNode().GetVolumeProperty().SetIndependentComponents(0)
```

Now i am trying this in my own Script in python with vtk. But i am missing the right translation from Slicer to Python VTK.

For a better Understanding, my Input Data is a Tifftack/MultiImageTiff in RBG and i read it in with the following code:

```
filename = "D:/SomeFilePath/Some_Tiff_Stack.tif"

colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

# renderer, render window
# and interactor.
ren1 = vtk.vtkRenderer()

renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren1)

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# Create the reader for the Tiff-Data (Multi-Image-Tiff)
reader = vtk.vtkTIFFReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
reader.SetDataSpacing(1,1,1)

# Create transfer mapping scalar value to opacity (configured in Slicer app).
opacityTransferFunction = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(0, 0)
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(20, 0)
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(40, 0.45)
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(98.26, 0.78)
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(255, 0)

# Create transfer mapping scalar value to color.
colorTransferFunction = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(0.0, 1, 1, 1)
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(64.0, 1.0, 1, 1)
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(128.0, 1.0, 1, 1.0)
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(192.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(255.0, 1, 1, 1)

# The property describes how the data will look.
volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(colorTransferFunction)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(opacityTransferFunction)
volumeProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()

'''
#This is what i need to translate to python/vtk
luminance = vtk.vtkImageLuminance()
luminance.SetInputConnection(colorVolume.GetImageDataConnection())
append=vtk.vtkImageAppendComponents()
append.AddInputConnection(colorVolume.GetImageDataConnection())
append.AddInputConnection(luminance.GetOutputPort())
append.Update()
colorVolume.SetAndObserveImageData(append.GetOutput())
volumeProperty.SetIndependentComponents(0)
'''
# The mapper / ray cast function know how to render the data.

#volumeMapper = vtk.vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper()
volumeMapper = vtk.vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper()
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)
#volumeProperty.SetIndependentComponents(0)

ren1.AddVolume(volume)
ren1.ResetCameraClippingRange()
ren1.ResetCamera()

renWin.SetSize(600, 600)
renWin.Render()

iren.Start()
```

If someone has any idea how to get this done, i realy appreciate any Help.
Until now, i "only" get a black Box surrounding my Image/Volume. With help of the alpha chanel i will be able to set the blackbox to transparent.

Best Regards
Bastian

Answer (score 0):

As a fix/translation i would suggest the following:

```
# create a default luminance map with the same size as the input image
luminance = vtk.vtkImageLuminance()
luminance.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

# merge the original image and the luminace map into one RGBA image
append = vtk.vtkImageAppendComponents()
append.AddInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
append.AddInputConnection(luminance.GetOutputPort())

volumeProperty.SetIndependentComponents(False)

# use the created RGBA image from the append as input for the mapper
volumeMapper = vtk.vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper()
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(append.GetOutputPort())
```

This will create a luminance map and merge it with the image into a RGBA image.

```
colorVolume.SetAndObserveImageData(append.GetOutput())
```

This line serves as a feedback of the created image into Slicer, which you don't need in this case, as you perform your own rendering.